# Signup and login using express and node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I am new to backend development and have been following an online course on mean stack development. It's a very basic course - just basic signup and login.
I have provided the code below. My problem is every time I try to signup I get **invalid user**. The page gets redirected to */auth/failure*. 
The course I have been following uses this exact same code yet gets the right result *i.e.* their signup is successful and their page gets directed to */auth/success*. Can someone please look into this code and point out whats wrong.

This is what I get (this is the screenshot of my window after testing my code on advanced rest client)

response headers:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnd3l.png)

request headers:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVyrv.png)

Any kind of help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Passport-init.js (javascript file where the passport-local module is exploited):

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
//temporary data store
var users = {};
module.exports = function(passport){

    // Passport needs to be able to serialize and deserialize users to support persistent login sessions
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {

        //tell passport which id to use for user
        console.log('serializing user:',user.username);

        //return the unique id for the user
        return done(null, user.username);
    });

    //Desieralize user will call with the unique id provided by serializeuser
    passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done) {

        //return user object back
        return done(null, users[username]);

    });

    passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback : true
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) { 
            //check if user exists
            if(!users[username]){
                return done('User Not Found', false);
            }

            //check if password is correct
            if(!isValidPassword(users[username], password)){
                return done('Invalid password ', false);
            }

            //sucessfully logged in
            console.log('sucessfully signed in');
            return done(null, users[username]);
        }
    ));

    passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {
            //check if the user already exists
            if (users[username]){
                return done('Username already exists', false);
            }

            //store user in memory 
            users[username] = {

                username: username,
                password: createHash(password)
            };

            console.log(users[username].username + ' Registration successful');
            return done(null, users[username]);
        })
    );

    var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
        return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    };
    // Generates hash using bCrypt
    var createHash = function(password){
        return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
    };

};
```

authenticate.js (javascript file for the routing):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(passport){

    //sends successful login state back to angular
    router.get('/success', function(req, res){
        res.send({state: 'success', user: req.user ? req.user : null});
    });

    //sends failure login state back to angular
    router.get('/failure', function(req, res){
        res.send({state: 'failure', user: null, message: "Invalid username or password"});
    });

    //log in
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect: '/auth/success',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/failure'
    }));

    //sign up
    router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
        successRedirect: '/auth/success',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/failure'
    }));

    //log out
    router.get('/signout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    return router;

}
```

app.js (main app file):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var api = require('./routes/api');
var authenticate = require('./routes/authenticate')(passport);

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/auth', authenticate);
app.use('/api', api);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

//// Initialize Passport
var initPassport = require('./passport-init');
initPassport(passport);

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "~2.5.7",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

There are two other files - api.js and app.js(main app file). I don't think there is a problem with those as I have tested them in the initial stages and they worked fine but If required I will post them as well.

EDIT: I added the app.js and package.json file

Comment: can you share package.json to see which dependency you are using

Comment: I added the package.json file.

Comment: As I can see you have'nt added any DB dependency like mongoose or mysql

Comment: Yes, that will be added later. I will be using MongoDB. This is just the first stage.MongoDB will be used in the next stage. I have been running my code on advanced rest client.

Comment: What are you request headers ? (not visible in the screenshot)

Comment: @piercus I edited the post and added request headers.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue here, sorry. I'm having `Found. Redirecting to /auth/success` when pasting all your files and running the request with `curl -d "username=user&password=one password" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://localhost:3000/auth/signup`. Are you able to test using curl ?

Comment: @piercus I tried it with curl just now. It works perfectly fine. I don't know why it doesn't on advanced rest client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **advanced rest client** you should put your parameters as **Body** parameters instead of putting them as **Headers** parameters.

[image]

Comment: I already have that file. It's the app.js file you are talking about. I have added the file to the query above.

Comment: @rinisaha i have updated my answer with your last remarks